# Python: Why do I get an "unexpected keyword argument" error?

Tags: python, constructor, keyword-argument

I am trying to set up a graph. For the initialization, I wanted the option of either starting with a collection of nodes and edges or not. So I gave them the default value None. Or so I thought:

```
def Graph():
    def __init__(self, nodes=None, edges=None, msg="test"):
        """
        assumes that the node and edge lists are the respective objects
        """
        if nodes == None:
            self.nodes = []
        else:
            self.nodes = nodes
            
        if edges == None:
            self.edges = []
        else:
            self.edges = edges
        
        self.node_names = []
        for node in nodes:
            self.node_names.append(node.get_name())
            
        self.msg = msg
```

(the msg part was for testing the code with the simplest example possible)

What I got was:

```
g = Graph(msg="33")
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-29-cc459c9baef3>", line 1, in <module>
    g = Graph(msg="33")

TypeError: Graph() got an unexpected keyword argument 'msg'
```

Can anybody help me? It's probably a ridiculously simply thing, but I just don't see it, and I'm going slightly mad here...

Comment: you probably want `for node in self.nodes`, not `for node in nodes`.  This is an observation, not an answer to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've defined `Graph` not as a class but as a regular function.

Replace `def Graph():` with `class Graph:`.

Comment: Okay, of all the mistakes I have ever made, this was probably the stupidest... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Declare "Graph" as a class.

```
class Graph():
    def __init__(self, nodes=None, edges=None, msg="test"):
        """
        assumes that the node and edge lists are the respective objects
        """
        ..
```